# How to check if a file contains email addresses or md5 using python

Tags: python, pandas

How to check if a source_file contains email addresses or md5 once you download

```
data2 = pd.read_csv(source_file, header=None)
```

tried using regrex and str.contains...but not able to figure out how to proceed

if that is checked then according to that i need to proceed for rest of the script

```
source_file1:

abd@gmail.com
xyz@gmail.com

source_file2:

d131dd02c5e6vrc4
55ad340609f4fw02
```

So far, I have tried:

```
if(data2['email/md5'].str.contains(r'[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z.]+')==1): print "yes"
```

Comment: What have you tried with regex?

Comment: if(data2['email/md5'].str.contains(r'[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z.]+')==1):
        print "yes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern `r'@\w+\.com'`.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(filename1, names=['email/md5'])

if df1['email/md5'].str.contains(r'@\w+\.com').all():
    print("Email")
else:
    print("md5")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well the question, you have 2 files, and you want to automatically detect which one has email adresses and which one has md5?

```
import re
import re
with open(source_file1, 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while not line:
        line = f.readline()
    #First line not empty containing a mail address
    if re.match('[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', f.readline()):
        mail_source_file = source_file1
        md5_source_file = source_file2
    else:
        md5_source_file = source_file1
        mail_source_file = source_file2
mail_dataframe = pd.read_csv(mail_source_file, header=None)
md5_dataframe = pd.read_csv(md5_source_file, header=None)
```

Does this help?

Comment: i am downloading the file from ftp like this:ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + source_file, open(source_file,'wb').write)
    data2 = pd.read_csv(source_file, header=None) from  this data2 i need to check for email and md5

Answer (score 0):

This might work, considering the hash as a 16 alphanumeric symbols and there are no invalid emails:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    getFile = myfile.read()
    # Emails
    numberOfEmails = len(re.findall(r'@(.*?).com', getFile))
    print "%d email(s) found"%(numberOfEmails)
    # MD5
    hashFormatCnt = 0
    splitFile = getFile.split()
    for str in splitFile:
        if re.match('^[\w-]+$', str):
            if len(str) == 16:
                hashFormatCnt = hashFormatCnt + 1
    print "%d look like hash found"%(hashFormatCnt)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to be more specific.

if you want to know how email looks, you can see it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax).

if you want to know how md5 looks, it usually is represented as 32 hex digits (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f).